# How to convert an array of doubles to a cell array of strings with the same length each?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I woould like to insert a space before each **positive** value in a matrix.

I start with:

```
A =
     1.0000   -0.2176    0.3766
    -0.2176    1.0000    0.3898
    -0.3766    0.3898    1.0000
```

I apply a function to each value of A:

```
B = arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x,'% 5.2f'),A,'UniformOutput',0)
```

And the ouput is this:

```
B = 
    '1.00'     '-0.22'    '0.38'
    '-0.22'    '1.00'     '0.39' 
    '-0.38'    '0.39'     '1.00'
```

However, I would like the output to be:

```
B = 
    ' 1.00'     '-0.22'    ' 0.38'
    '-0.22'     ' 1.00'    ' 0.39' 
    '-0.38'     ' 0.39'    ' 1.00'
```

Notice that each cell has the **same width** (5 characters), no matter if the numb is positive or negative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the plus for equal length, then replace it with a blank

```
B = arrayfun(@(x) strrep(num2str(x,'%+5.2f'),'+',' '),A,'Uni',false)
```

If your question is just about equal length, use:

```
B = arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x,'%+5.2f'),A,'Uni',false)
```

or

```
B = arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x,'%05.2f'),A,'Uni',false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid `arrayfun` and vectorize the conversion by using the precision property of `num2str` to apply it to the whole matrix directly:

```
prec = 2
B = mat2cell(num2str(A,'%+5.2f'), ones(size(A,1),1), (prec+3).*ones(size(A,2),1))
```

---

```
B = 

    '+1.00'    '-0.22'    '+0.38'
    '-0.22'    '+1.00'    '+0.39'
    '-0.38'    '+0.39'    '+1.00'
```

---

**Explanation:**

```
%// apply num2str to whole matrix with precision property
charArray = num2str(A,'%+5.2f');
%// reshape resulting char array
B = mat2cell(charArray, [1 1 1], [3+2 3+2 3+2])
%// which is generically
B = mat2cell(charArray, ones(size(A,1),1), (prec+3).*ones(size(A,2),1))
```

---

**Benchmark:**

```
f1 = @() mat2cell(num2str(A,'%+5.2f'), ones(size(A,1),1), (prec+3).*ones(size(A,2),1));
f2 = @() arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x,'%+5.2f'),A,'Uni',false);

t1 = timeit(f1)
t2 = timeit(f2)
```

---

```
t1 =   0.25875  %// mat2cell
t2 =   4.2812   %// arrayfun
```

So for a `200x100` matrix, the `mat2cell` solution is almost **20 times** faster than `arrayfun`.